# wcf CS0012 puzzle with nested type

Tags: c#, wcf, datacontract

Sorry if this is obvious but I am pulling my hair over this issue: I have a class library ClassLibrary1 that defines `Class1`, and a WCF Service Library WcfServiceLibrary1 referencing ClassLibrary1 that defines a class `Response` in which Class1 is nested:

```
    public class Response
{
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public Class1 Value { get; set; }
}
```

Then I added a simple console application as client referencing WcfServiceLibrary1 (but not ClassLibrary1, to simulate separation between business logic and client logic).  However I cannot compile WcfServiceLibrary1 as I get error "CS0012 The type 'Class1' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'ClassLibrary1..."

What am I missing?  Thanks

Class1.cs:

```
namespace ClassLibrary1
{
    public class Class1
    {
        public int SomeInt { get; set; }
    }
}
```

IService1.cs:

```
namespace WcfServiceLibrary1
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IService1
    {
        [OperationContract]
        Response ConvertToClass(int value);

        [OperationContract]
        Class1 AltConvertToClass(int value);
    }

    public class Response
    {
        public string Message { get; set; }
        public Class1 Value { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Service1.cs:

```
namespace WcfServiceLibrary1
{
    public class Service1 : IService1
    {
        public Response ConvertToClass(int value)
        {
            return new Response() {Message = "Success", Value = new Class1() {SomeInt = value}};
        }

        public Class1 AltConvertToClass(int value)
        {
            return new Class1() {SomeInt = value};
        }
    }
}
```

Program.cs:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var client = new ServiceReference1.Service1Client();
            client.Open();

            Console.Write("Enter number:");
            var s = Console.ReadLine();

            var n = int.Parse(s);

            var c = client.ConvertToClass(n);
            Console.WriteLine($"Result: Message = {c.Message}, Value = {c.Value}"); //CS0012
            var c2 = client.AltConvertToClass(n);
            Console.WriteLine($"Result: {c2.SomeInt}");

            Console.WriteLine("\nPress enter...");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: P.S.: Only `Console.WriteLine($"Result: Message = {c.Message}, Value = {c.Value}");` generates an error, and not `Console.WriteLine($"Result: {c2.SomeInt}");`, so it is not true that a reference to ClassLibrary1 must imperatively be added...  That's what's the puzzle is all about!

Comment: You can download the project here: [link](https://www.amazon.com/clouddrive/share/ucA0XxMlppZFzIQMYnKM3QSOSmnXT97FBjicNpHU6Su?ref_=cd_ph_share_link_copy)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error comes from `ConsoleApplication1` (the client) referencing `WcfServiceLibrary1` (the host), causing the automatically generated service code in [ConsoleApplication1 -> Service References -> ServiceReference1 -> Reference.svcmap -> Reference.cs] to reuse `WcfServiceLibrary1.Response` (which relies on `ClassLibrary1.Class1` whence CS0012) yet otherwise creates ServiceReference1.Class1 to deal with the `AltConvertToClass` method.

The solution is to remove the reference from `ConsoleApplication1` (the client) to `WcfServiceLibrary1` (the host), which makes perfect sense since the two assemblies will typically be run on separate machines.

Thanks everyone for your contributions!

Comment: Note that `ConsoleApplication1` will only deal with the automatically generated copycat `ServiceReference1.Class1` without any code you would typically have in `ClassLibrary1.Class1`.  You can either copy the relevant code from `ClassLibrary1.Class1` to the `ConsoleApplication1` project, or place any shared code in a separate assembly as Joao suggested.

Comment: Note that you are still ending up with duplicate code here. You can remove this duplicated code by creating a contract project that both the client and the service reference.

Comment: it is a bit rude to mark your own answer as the solution when your initial question asked "what are you missing". I explained what you are missing and yet you did not flag my answer as the correct answer.

Comment: I apparently can only mark one answer as "the" answer. Thank you very much for your time and help, I wish there was a way to distinguish people like you better. However I feel your answer promoted a general approach described in your blog, and while it makes a lot of sense it does not address the root cause of CS0012 here, namely that the client is referencing the host, causing the automatically generated Reference.cs to get confused. Others running into the same issue are likely to find this page and be interested in your approach, so you're still getting a fair amount of visibility, no?

Answer (score 0):

Exactly what the error says.

Regardless of your design intentions, by referencing `Class1` in `WcfServiceLibrary1`, you have made `ClassLibrary1` a dependency of `WcfServiceLibrary1`.

No other component can reference `WcfServiceLibrary1` without also referencing `ClassLibrary1`.

You will have to revisit your design.

Comment: Not strictly true. If `WcfServiceLibrary1` merely uses types from `ClassLibrary1` internally/privately then consumers of that library don't need a `ClassLibrary1` reference. *Here* it is required because `WcfServiceLibrary1` is exposing the `ClassLibrary1` types in return values from functions.

Comment: If that is the case, how do you explain that only `Console.WriteLine($"Result: Message = {c.Message}, Value = {c.Value}");` generates an error, and not `Console.WriteLine($"Result: {c2.SomeInt}");` ?

Answer (score 0):

**Update 1**

After looking at your solution, the issue is that you are generating a service reference, which creates copies of the classes that are needed by your service. Open ConsoleApplication1 -> Service References -> ServiceReference1 -> Reference.svcmap -> Reference.cs and you will see that it has generated a class called `Class1` in the namespace `ConsoleApplication1.ServiceReference1`. This was done because the project has not referenced your `ClassLibrary1` solution. It did not generate the code for the Response object as this has already been referenced in your console project. So the result is that:

1. The call `AltConvertToClass` returns an object of type `ConsoleApplication1.ServiceReference1.Class1`
2. The call `ConvertToClass` returns an object of type `WcfServiceLibrary1.Response`, which contains an object of type `ClassLibrary1.Class1` (which is different to the one above), resulting in a compiler error

I suggest you follow the tutorial I linked to below, as that IMHO is the correct way to do service oriented architecture. Leave service references alone - it ends up duplicating code.

Otherwise, you can fix your code as follows:

1. Create a contract project and move the interface (`IService1`) and DTOs (your `Response` class is a DTO, and as you are returning `Class1`, that is a DTO too) to this project.
2. Service project containing the implementation (`Service1`) should reference your contract class
3. Console application should reference your contract project
4. Update your service reference

**Original**

You still need to reference any projects whose classes you use. As `Class1` is used in your console application, it needs to reference `ClassLibrary1`.

If you want to separate your business logic from your client application, you cannot reference any classes in your business logic classes in your client application. If you want to return any objects in your `Response` class, you should rather create a contract library to contain your DTOs (Data-transfer objects) and map your domain classes to DTO classes, and reference the contract project in both the server and the client.

I wrote a tutorial a while ago about this architecture at http://lourenco.co.za/blog/2013/08/wcf-windows-service-using-topshelf-and-servicemodelex/ . **Disclaimer - I wrote this tutorial!**

Comment: Thanks it's a good tutorial but it doesn't really solve the puzzle: why Class1 only causes CS0012 when nested inside another class, but not as direct return type?

Comment: Could you upload a copy of your solution? The only thing I can think of is that there is another Class1.cs class somewhere in your project that is not referenced.

Comment: You can download the project here: [link](https://www.amazon.com/clouddrive/share/ucA0XxMlppZFzIQMYnKM3QSOSmnXT97FBjicNpHU6Su?ref_=cd_ph_share_link_copy)

Comment: Thank you for your update pointing to Reference.cs, I now realize that the inconsistency is coming from ConsoleApplication1 referencing WcfServiceLibrary1.  Once I remove the reference everything compiles.